# Django opening SQLServer Reports with Basic Authentication

Tags: django

I have a requirement to open SQLServer reports from my Django site. I can do this by redirecting to the report server URL in a Django view after storing the URL in the session, i.e.:

```
def show_report(request):     
    return redirect(request.session.get('_reporturl'))
```

This works fine but I want to avoid the ReportServer prompting for a username and password.  I've concluded (possibly incorrectly) the best way to do this would be to use HTTP basic authentication.

I found the following code in another post for basic auth:

```
import urllib2, base64
username = '<username>'
password = '<password>'
request = urllib2.Request(request.session.get('_reporturl'))
base64string = base64.standard_b64encode('%s:%s' % (username, password))
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

However I can't get this to work in a view (a Django view needs to return an HTTPResponse, so I'm unsure how to use this code).

I've tried the following:

```
return redirect('http://<username>:<password>@' + request.session.get('_reporturl'))
```

This seems to pass the basic auth data to the report server but I get several further prompts for username and password.

Has anyone managed to use basic auth in Django, or has anyone managed to open SQLServer reports without being prompted for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this by configuring Apache to proxy to the report server:

```
LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule xml2enc_module modules/mod_proxy_html/mod_xml2enc.so
Include modules/mod_proxy_html/proxy_html.conf

# set up proxy for SQL Server reports
<Location /ReportServer/>
  ProxyPass http://<reportserver>/ReportServer/
  ProxyPassReverse http://<reportserver>/ReportServer/
  SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0  1
  SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive        1
  SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled 1
  ProxyHTMLEnable On
  ProxyHTMLURLMap http://<reportserver>/ReportServer/ /ReportServer/
  # Base64 encoding of "username:password"
  RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic <base64 encoded string>"
</Location>
```

mod_proxy_html is a third party module downloaded from http://www.apachelounge.com/download/win32/modules-2.2/mod_proxy_html-3.1.2-win32.zip - open the zip and dump the mod_proxy_html folder under Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\modules.  The necessary config is included in the above section.  (It seems to be included in later versions of Apache.)

mod_proxy_html might not be strictly necessary – the ProxyPassReverse directive is the important one I think – so if it causes problems, you can remove the three lines doing LoadModule/Include and remove the ProxyHTML lines in the Location section.